# AWS API Gateway deployment history with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

If I use `aws_api_gateway_deployment` like this, when I increment `api_gateway_deployment_trigger` and run `terraform apply`, terraform replaces the existing API Gateway deployment with a new one:

```
variable "api_gateway_deployment_trigger" {
  type        = string
  description = "Increment this to force creating an API GW deployment."
  default     = "3"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "this" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.this
  description = "Lambda function integration."

  triggers = {
    redeploy = filebase64sha256("api-gateway.tf")  # this path refers to this TerraForm source file
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_integration.api_integration,
  ]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "deploy_stage" {
  deployment_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.this.id
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.this.id
  stage_name    = var.stage_name
}
```

That makes sense to me: Terraform is handling `aws_api_gateway_deployment` the same as any other resource. However, I would like to retain a few recent API Gateway deployments in order to be able to roll back to old deployments.

How can I use Terraform such that:

1. A history is kept of a few recent API Gateway deployments
2. It's possible to use Terraform to roll back to an old deployment given a deployment id

Comment: I can't say for certain, but I don't think you can. There is only one Gateway in your configuration, so that's what TF will drive to be the situation when it has completed an `apply` operation. Beyond that, I can't think of a way to include "a few" gateways whose identities just change during a deployment. It *might* be possible to get TF to just forget about an old Gateway rather than deleting it, but then they wouldn't be managed and I don't know how you would roll back to them anyway

Comment: You mean deployments, not gateways, right?

Comment: As for your point: I'm imagining it might be possible to use a TF data source that fetches the previous deployment, to define a second "previous" deployment resource, for example?

Comment: Maaaybe? I'm not convinced though: the very first time you deploy there won't be one to find; I don't know how you'd automatically delete the old ones after N deployments; I'm still not sure how you'd roll back to an older one using TF. I'm curious to see what you make if you happen to get it working. And yes, I guess I mean deployments rather than gateways - it's been a couple of years since I've used them and can't remember all the details

Answer (score 2):

This is not something you can do with the existing Terraform API Gateway resources. As you mentioned, `aws_api_gateway_deployment` will recreate the deployment, not create a new version. Each `aws_api_gateway_deployment` resource correlates to a deployment row in the deployment history tab of the stage in the AWS Console. The "Change Deployment" button in the AWS console correlates to changing the `deployment_id` of the `aws_api_gateway_stage` resource in terraform.

I would recommend using version control and continuous deployment pipelines with Terraform to achieve a similar functionality. When your terraform is changed, commit and push the changes to git and have a deployment pipeline such as CodePipelines execute the Terraform code to update the resources. That way, the pipeline will track the change history of your entire environment. If you want to rollback to a previous API version, just revert back to the commit of the version you want.

Another option would be to leverage the `aws_api_gateway_export` [resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/api_gateway_export) and the aws cli `import-rest-api` [command](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/2.0.33/reference/apigateway/import-rest-api.html). You could have the export save the API spec to a local location or S3 and use a `local-exec` resource to execute an import of the specified API spec by executing the `import-rest-api` command. Thus, each deployment ID could be tracked and you could execute a rollback by providing the deployment ID as an optional variable to your terraform apply command. This would not have a history of deployments on the API gateway resource, but it would track each deployment as an exported API spec.

Comment: I suspect if I want to take advantage of versioning / rollback at the API GW level, I should probably create API GW deployments from CI outside of TF, just using the AWS API.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @ToDevAndBeyond, this cannot be achieved using the current Terraform API Gateway resources. Furthermore, when Lambda is employed to handle requests, a similar issue arises with the `aws_lambda_permission` resource. It is imperative to ensure that each deployment corresponds to its respective Lambda version; otherwise, there is no motivation to roll back to previous deployments when all of them are served by the same Lambda version.

When `aws_lambda_permission` is configured for the Lambda function itself, the resource-based policy is not automatically replicated to newly published versions. Conversely, when configured for a specific Lambda version, it is recreated each time a new version is published. Consequently, the previous versions become inaccessible for the API Gateway.

However, there is a workaround to address this issue by creating the deployment and lambda resource policy for specific version outside of Terraform using the AWS CLI or APIs. By doing so, these resources are excluded from Terraform's management.

I have implemented a sample solution that addresses this challenge, which you can find here: https://github.com/nicolai-budico/apigw-deployment-history/

Please note that all resources, including stages and method settings, are managed by Terraform, except for `aws_api_gateway_deployment` and `aws_lambda_permission`.

For a more detailed explanation of the problem and the solution, please refer to this document: https://github.com/nicolai-budico/apigw-deployment-history/blob/main/about.md

I hope this information proves helpful.